# python - filtering part of a object

Tags: python, forms, key

In python 2.7, I'm pulling a key from a website and assigning it to a object.

My output is this `u'sXQcmAT4u5v1w71d'`

How can i take just the `sXQcmAT4u5v1w71d` part and assign it to a new object?

Comment: yes you can but don't post keys for the public to see

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see any Python codes.

Comment: Maybe switch to Python 3.x and work in unicode?

Comment: ```u'sXQcmAT4u5v1w71d'.encode('ascii')``` - if you want the ascii character set

Comment: or `str(u'sXQcmAT4u5v1w71d')`?

Comment: I'm sorry guys i didn't realize that the u is unicode format, new to this thank you for your responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u'sXQcmAT4u5v1w71d'` is marked the value is `Unicode` format. The output's value is `'sXQcmAT4u5v1w71d'`.

So if you want assign the data to the new object, just do like this:

```
t_str = u'sXQcmAT4u5v1w71d'
```